# How do I get only the value of a column identified by a unique userid in MySQL? pls refer to Question for more detailed explanation

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql-python, mysql-connector

I'm currently writing an rpg game in python that uses a mysql database to store info on players. However, I've come across a problem.

**Sample Code of How Database has been Set Up:**

```
playerinfo Table
userID | money | xp |
  1    | 200   | 20 |
  2    | 100   | 10 |
```

I'm trying to select the amount of money with only the value. My select query right now is

`SELECT money FROM playerinfo WHERE id = 1`

The full code/function for collecting selecting the info is

```
def get_money_stats(user_id):
    global monresult
    remove_characters = ["{", "}", "'"]
    try:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            monsql = "SELECT money FROM players WHERE userid = %s"
            value = user_id
            cursor.execute(monsql, value)
            monresult = str(cursor.fetchone())
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error Occurred>  {e}")
```

**CURRENT OUTPUT:**

`{'money': 200}`

**DESIRED OUTPUT:**

`200`

Basically, all I want to select is the INT/DATA from the player's row (identified by unique userid). How do I do that? The only solution I have is to replace the characters with something else but I don't really want to do that as it's incredibly inconvenient and messy. Is there another way to reformat/select the data?

Comment: Maybe you want: `monresult = cursor.fetchone()[0]`?

Comment: Why `[0]` instead of `[1]`?

Comment: I think fetchone() should return a tuple in your case (200,) right?

Comment: It's currently returning `{'money': 0}`, so I believe that it's a dict, not a tuple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like that fetching one row gives you a dictionary of the selected columns with its values, which seems the correct approach to me. You should simply access the dictionary with the column that you want to retrieve:

```
monresult = cursor.fetchone()['money']
```

If you don't want to specify again the column (which you should) you could get the values of the dictionary as a list and retrieve the first one:

```
monresult = list(cursor.fetchone().values())[0]
```

I do not recommend the last approach because it's heavily dependent on the current status of the query and it may have to change if the query is changed.